# Линия до и после текста над картинкой

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Я хочу создать линию до и после центрированного заголовка. Линия и текст должны иметь прозрачный фон, чтобы иметь возможность позиционировать их на неодинаковом фоне. Строка не должна быть больше 100% ширины.

Как здесь на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст заголовка может измениться:

- Ширина заголовка неизвестна
- Заголовок может занимать несколько строк

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}         


 <h1>Today</h1>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23584120/7394871) от участника  [@JUO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649866/juo).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584120/line-before-and-after-title-over-image/23584310#23584310

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Нестандартное решение )) :

```css
fieldset {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Lorem ipsum.</legend>
  </fieldset>
```

Более стандартное:

```css
header {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}

h1:before {
  right: 100%;
  left: -1000%;
}

h1:after {
  left: 100%;
  right: -1000%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    <h1>
      Lorem ipsum.
    </h1>
  </header>
</section>
```

[ex](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/wWzWRw?editors=1100) , [ex](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/qqWzYE?editors=1100)

Comment: первое решение как раз выглядит более "стандартным" =)

Comment: @vp_arth, я обычно вторым пользуюсь)

Answer (score 11):

Вы можете сделать линию по обеим сторонам заголовка с 2 псевдоэлементами и границами:

- Это работает на `transparent background` (линии и название имеют
  прозрачные фоны).
- Длина линии адаптируется к ширине заголовка, поэтому они всегда
  начинаются и заканчиваются с одинаковыми пробелами независимо от
  длины заголовка.
- Заголовок может занимать несколько строк, в то время как левая и
  правая линии остаются вертикально центрированными (обратите внимание,
  что вам нужно обернуть заголовок тегом `span`, чтобы это работало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300);
 body {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/EzOh4DX.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  width: 70%;
  margin: .7em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:300;
  color: #fff;
}
h1:before, h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 -55%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
h1:after {
  margin: 0 -55% 0 .5em;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Today</h1>
<h1>Today news</h1>
<h1><span>Today<br/>news</span></h1>
```

<sub>Перевод ответа [Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584310/7394871) от участника  [@иweb-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Answer (score 11):

Вот еще один подход, используя дисплей flexbox. Свойство `flex-grow` определяет, как свободное пространство должно распределяться между элементами, когда их общий размер меньше размера контейнера.
По умолчанию для элементов, описывающие строки, `width` не указана, и у них нет содержимого (то есть они в основном пусты и не занимают места).  Однако применение `flex-grow` на этих элементах обеспечивала бы равномерное распределение между ними оставшегося пространства (общее пространство контейнера - пространство текста).  Это заставляет линию выглядеть так, как будто она проходит от начала до конца  за исключением того места, где находится текст.

**Сплошная линия по обе стороны контента:**

В приведенном ниже фрагменте, градиент сверху вниз используется для создания эффекта сплошной линии с обеих сторон контента.

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white);
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Just for demo*/
body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader and broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader<br/> and spans multiple <br/> no. of lines</h3>

<!-- IE11 specific version -->

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='before'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  Something broader and broader and broader
  <span class='after'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Линия с градиентным эффектом с обеих сторон контента:**

В приведенном ниже фрагменте, тонкий градиент слева направо используется для создания эффекта линии, которая идет от сплошного цвета рядом с текстом к прозрачному с другой стороны.

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading:before, .heading:after,
.heading-ie span.after, .heading-ie span.before{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.heading:before, .heading-ie span.before{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, white);
}
.heading:after, .heading-ie span.after{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, white);
}

/* Just for demo*/
body{
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader and broader</h3>
<h3 class='heading'>Something broader<br/> and spans multiple <br/> no. of lines</h3>

<!-- IE11 specific version -->

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='before'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  Something broader and broader and broader
  <span class='after'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

Примечание. В фрагменте я использовал дополнительные элементы `span` для строк, потому что `IE11`, по-видимому, не поддерживает `flex-grow` для псевдоэлементов. В противном случае то же самое может быть достигнуто и с псевдоэлементом.

---

Недостатком этого подхода является довольно низкая поддержка браузерами этой функции.

Вам также может потребоваться адаптировать некоторые настройки браузера, которые подробно описаны в моем ответе [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898287/how-to-display-text-a-dotted-line-then-more-text-spanning-the-width-of-the-page/28629080#28629080), который подобен этому.

В настоящее время это не дает ничего сверх ответа `@web-tiki`, но является еще одним возможным вариантом. Такой подход был бы **более полезным в случаях, подобных приведенным ниже:**

```css
h3{
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.heading-ie .start, .heading-ie .middle, .heading-ie .end{
  content: '';
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0px 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white);
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size: 100% 2px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* Order specifies the order in which the elements should be presen within container */

.content-1{
  order: 2;
}
.start{
  order: 1;
}
.middle{
  order: 3;
}
.content-2{
  order: 4;
}
.end{
  order: 5;
}

/* Just for demo*/

body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #3F9CBA 0%, #153346 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='start'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-1'>Text here</span>
  <span class='middle'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-2'>and here too</span>
  <span class='end'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>

<h3 class='heading-ie'>
  <span class='start'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-1'>Text with <br/> line break</span>
  <span class='middle'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
  <span class='content-2'>and here with <br/> line break too</span>
  <span class='end'></span> <!-- IE11 supports flex-grow only on actual elements -->
</h3>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Line before and after title over image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30736618/7394871) от участника  [@Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry).</sub>